# tcp connection reset [RST, ACK]

Tags: apache-2.2, tcp, javascript

getting this errors looks like server is restating the connection because of some packet loss

any possible suggestion's to figure out this

```
        37713   591.925575000   Sourceip==>>destinationIP TCP 66  50865→https [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=4 SACK_PERM=1
        37719   592.196621000   destinationIP==>>Sourceip TCP 66  https→50865 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14600 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 WS=32
        37720   592.196714000   Sourceip==>>destinationIP TCP 54  50865→https [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65700 Len=0
        37721   592.197041000   Sourceip==>>destinationIP TCP 296 50865→https [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=65700 Len=242
        37731   592.467777000   destinationIP==>>Sourceip TCP 60  https→50865 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=243 Win=15680 Len=0
        37732   592.472448000   destinationIP==>>Sourceip TCP 1514https→50865 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=243 Win=15680 Len=1460
        37733   592.472449000   destinationIP==>>Sourceip TCP 63  https→50865 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1461 Ack=243 Win=15680 Len=9
        37734   592.472567000   Sourceip==>>destinationIP TCP 54  50865→https [ACK] Seq=243 Ack=1470 Win=65700 Len=0
        37735   592.477202000   Sourceip==>>destinationIP TCP 180 50865→https [PSH, ACK] Seq=243 Ack=1470 Win=65700 Len=126
        37738   592.748678000   destinationIP==>>Sourceip TCP 328 https→50865 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1470 Ack=369 Win=15680 Len=274
        37742   592.948569000   Sourceip==>>destinationIP TCP 54  50865→https [ACK] Seq=369 Ack=1744 Win=65424 Len=0
        43411   608.487555000   Sourceip==>>destinationIP TCP 54  50865→https [FIN, ACK] Seq=369 Ack=1744 Win=65424 Len=0
        43425   608.758989000   destinationIP==>>Sourceip TCP 85  https→50865 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1744 Ack=370 Win=15680 Len=31
        43426   608.758990000   destinationIP==>>Sourceip TCP 60  https→50865 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1775 Ack=370 Win=15680 Len=0
==>==>==>43427   608.766008000   Sourceip==>>destinationIP TCP 54  50865→https [RST, ACK] Seq=370 Ack=1775 Win=0 Len=0  <==<==<==
```

i am using javascript(chrome extension) persistant connection at client and apache2 php at server end

and at this moment i get this error `Provisional headers are shown`

Comment: Client is and server are closing connection (sending fin,ack each), don't see any packet loss. I think the problem is not at tcp level but higher up.

Comment: Nothing crazy, the client sends its termination sequence and the server push the data remaining then sends its termination sequence too. The client sends a reset so the connection is closed bypassing CLOSE_WAIT/LAST_ACK states. That's quite common with browsers.

Comment: so any possible suggestion for this error `Provisional headers are shown` after reading this i am totally confused http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger